# Spring unusual error

Tags: java, spring

Good night.I have a Incomprehensible bug in the injection of the object and I do not understand what it is and how this obviate, Internet search returned no results, no one solution did not help. I would be grateful if you could explain the reason.

ReminderService bean

```
@Service("ReminderService")
public class ReminderService implements dbService<Reminder> 
{
@Autowired
private JpaReminder jpaReminder;

@Transactional
public List<Reminder> getAll() 
{
    return jpaReminder.findAll();
}

@Transactional
public Reminder get(Object id) 
{
    return jpaReminder.find(id);
}

}
```

JpaReminder bean,

```
@Repository("JpaReminder")
public class JpaReminder extends jpaDao<Reminder>
{
private EntityManager em;

/**
 * @return Возвращает entityManager
 */
@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() 
{
    return em;
}

public EntityManager getEm() 
{
    return em;
}

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TaskTracker")
public void setEm(EntityManager em) 
{
    this.em = em;
}

}
```

Stack Trace error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ReminderService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder com.work.Spring.mainClass.ReminderService.jpaReminder; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JpaReminder' defined in file [/home/qwerty/Eclipse/Spring/target/classes/com/work/Spring/Dao/JpaReminder.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.work.Spring.App.main(App.java:22)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder com.work.Spring.mainClass.ReminderService.jpaReminder; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JpaReminder' defined in file [/home/qwerty/Eclipse/Spring/target/classes/com/work/Spring/Dao/JpaReminder.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
... 13 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JpaReminder' defined in file [/home/qwerty/Eclipse/Spring/target/classes/com/work/Spring/Dao/JpaReminder.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
... 15 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
... 26 more

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.work.Interfaces.jpaDao.<init>(jpaDao.java:24)
at com.work.Spring.Dao.JpaReminder.<init>(JpaReminder.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 28 more
```

Comment: The problem is in the constructor for `jpaDao`.  You'll need to show us that too.  Preferably with an indication of which line is number 24.

Comment: Did you provide the full body of `JpaReminder`? If no, please do. Otherwise, could you provide your `applicationContext.xml` too?

Answer (score 3):

From the exception's stacktrace, it is evident that the constructor code of `JpaReminder` is throwing `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.`

Since `JpaReminder` is extending `jpaDao` and `JpaReminder` doesn't have its own constructor then, `jpaDao`'s (or its parent class's) constructor is culprit

You can debug the code and find out more

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar exception in my application when I was using Java 8 with Spring version less than 4. I had to either upgrade to Spring 4 or change the lambdas so I did the latter.

This was quite hard to know, because the error is so vague. Nothing to do with arrays, really.